# SoundClound track_count for client_id different than the real count when listing the tracks

Tags: soundcloud

I'm using the Python API but also found this out using normal HTTP requests.

So the issue is the following, when querying for a channel information I get a specific number of track_count, but when I list all the tracks the track count is different, in this case is bigger by 2.

Ex: `https://api.soundcloud.com/users/<user_id>?client_id=<client_id>` will give me in this specific case that the track count is of 1138

Then when paginating using linked_partitioning=1 as `https://api.soundcloud.com/users/<user_id>/tracks?client_id=<client_id>&limit=200&linked_partitioning=1` as per documentation, I get a total of 1140, when following the `next_href`. Using Python I found that 2 are repeated.

Is this something usual or there is a bug there?

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug from soundcloud's POV

I've seen this in many platforms using that, including big ones like [theartistunion.com](https://theartistunion.com/) and on several mobile apps.

I don't see any workaround this

Comment: of course, if you always get the same view difference (like 2 plays more) you can just set it manually in a variable